# Can you rely on an element ID assigned by jQuery?

Tags: jquery, iframe

I am working on a website that has some poortly thought out HTML code with alot of elements without ID or classes. I am limited to manipulating the HTML with jQuery (or javascript) only. The website has an iFrame without an identifier, but I need to do a bunch of stuff with that iFrame and its contents so I use jQuery to assign an ID (called upload_frame) to the frame like so:

```
$("iFrame", window.parent.document).each(function() {
        var src = $(this).attr("src");
        var search = "upload.asp";
        if( src && src.indexOf(search) != -1){
            $(this).attr("id", "upload_frame");
        }
    });
```

(The jQuery is executed from within another iframe, hence the window.parent.document part when I target any element.) Now, the problem I run into is that I use the ID assigned above on different places throughout my js file, and **sometimes** it seems like parts of my code are simply not executed. There are no errors generated. Could this be because that code is being executed before the iframe was assigned the ID I use in the rest of my jQuery code? Is this a timing issue?

Comment: You are assigning ID to only one iframe or more? If one, why using each loop?

Comment: There is no problem if you assign a new ID to the element via DOM or jQuery functions. You can catch that new iframe with: `$('iframe#upload_frame')`. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just do:

```
$("iframe[src*='upload.asp']");
```

I see no point in adding the ID with jQuery. Either use the selector above, or if you do choose to use a loop, once you've found the correct iframe, just reference that. Don't give it an ID to find it again, thats counter-intuitive.

```
var $uploadIframe;
$("iFrame", window.parent.document).each(function() {
    var src = $(this).attr("src");
    var search = "upload.asp";
    if( src && src.indexOf(search) != -1){
        $uploadIframe = $(this);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on improving the way the iframe element is selected. Although it does not directly answer my question, at least I can rule out the loading of the iframe is not causing other jQuery to sometimes not being executed.

Comment: No problem @Marc. It doesn't answer your question, but I believe it solves your issue in a better way than an answer to your question could.